IllegalArgumentException while adding link in Spring Boot hateos
I have my controller set up and all path variables are coming through but when trying to add a link using linkTo() method it gives an exception.
Here is my controller:
@GetMapping(value = {
            "/competitions/rounds/roundTypes",
            "/tenants/{tenantId}/orgs/{orgId}/programs/{programId}/competitions/{competitionId}/rounds/roundTypes",
            "/tenants/{tenantId}/orgs/{orgId}/programs/{programId}/rounds/roundTypes"},
            produces = "application/hal+json")
    public HttpEntity<RepresentationModel<RoundTypeResponse>> getRoundTypes(@PathVariable(required = false) Integer tenantId,
                                                                            @PathVariable(required = false) Integer orgId,
                                                                            @PathVariable(required = false) Integer programId,
                                                                            @PathVariable(required = false) UUID competitionId,
                                                                            @RequestHeader(value="X-TENANT-ID") String xTenantId
    ) {
        log.info("Request received to get round types... ");
        Utils.compareTenantIds(xTenantId,tenantId);
        Round round = new Round();
        round.setTenantId(tenantId);
        round.setOrgId(orgId);
        round.setProgramId(programId);
        round.setCompetitionId(competitionId != null ? competitionId.toString() : null);

        List<RoundType> dbRoundTypes = competitionServiceِِِِِِ.getRoundTypes(round);
        RoundTypes roundTypes = new RoundTypes(dbRoundTypes.size(), dbRoundTypes);
        RoundTypeResponse roundTypeResponse = new RoundTypeResponse();
        roundTypeResponse.setContent(roundTypes);

        roundTypeResponse.add(linkTo(methodOn(CompetitionController_V2.class).getRoundTypes(tenantId, orgId, programId, competitionId,xTenantId )).withSelfRel());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(roundTypeResponse, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

Below is the exception:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No variable named tenantId found!

But tenantID is present in the parameter as well as it was passed in the request as path var.

When there are multiple urls to an endpoint then linkTo uses the first one.
In your case this is "/competitions/rounds/roundTypes" which does not have a variable called tenantId.
I would suggest you reorder the urls at your endpoint to put the second one first, as it includes all parameters.
